# Cucumber + Devise - signing in issues -> current_user always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, capybara

I have a cucumber test where I log into the system and then check some routing

```
Feature: Donating as a guest

  @javascript
  Scenario: Logged in as an Admin
    Given I login as AdminUser
    And I go to the root page
    And I click button "$20"
    And I click button "Donate"
    And I click link "Donate as Guest >"
    Then I am redirected to "sign_in_or_sign_up" with flash message stating "You're logged in as an Admin"
```

Here is my step where I log in (note cucumber says this passes):

```
Given(/^I login as AdminUser$/) do
  admin = Fabricate(:admin_user)
  Fabricate(:fund)

  visit '/admin/admin_users/sign_in'
  fill_in 'Email', :with => admin.email
  fill_in 'Password', :with => admin.password
  click_button 'Sign in'
end
```

On the second two last step, **And I click link "Donate as Guest >"**, my funds controller makes a check to see what kind of current_user is logged in.

```
if current_user.class == AdminUser
```

Every time it hits here, current_user is nil. I am stumped why this is. I've even tried logging in programmatically, but no go. Is there some sort of wiring up I am missing?

**Edit:**

Here is my routes pertaining to this:

```
devise_for :admin_users

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "user/omniauth_callbacks", :sessions => 'user/sessions', :passwords => 'user/passwords',  :confirmations => 'user/confirmations'}
devise_scope :user do
  get '/user/auth/:provider' => 'user/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
  get     "/user/sign_in"   => "devise/sessions#new",         :as => :new_user_session
  post    "/user/sign_in"   => "user/sessions#create",      :as => :user_session
  delete  "/user/sign_out"  => "devise/sessions#destroy",     :as => :destroy_user_session
  post    "/user/sign_up"   => "user/registrations#create", :as => :user_registration
  get     "/user/sign_in_or_sign_up" => "user/sessions#sign_in_or_sign_up"
  post    "/user/sign_up_via_dual_login" => "user/registrations#create_via_dual_login"
end
```

AdminUser model:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  attr_accessible(
    :email,
    :password,
    :password_confirmation,
    :remember_me,
    :organization_id,
    :organization_role_id,
    :super_admin,
    :first_name,
    :last_name,
    :receive_transaction_notifications,
    :receive_weekly_transaction_summary
  )

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :roles, :foreign_key => :api_user_id
  belongs_to :organization_role, :class_name => "UserRole", :foreign_key => "organization_role_id"
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :admin_users_connections
  has_many :people, through: :admin_users_connections
  has_and_belongs_to_many :todos
  has_many :notes, foreign_key: :added_by_id
  has_one :profile

  scope :admins, where( :super_admin => false, active: true)
  scope :super, where(super_admin: true)
  scope :receive_weekly_transaction_summaries, where(receive_weekly_transaction_summary: true)


  def type
    super_admin? && 'SUPER' || 'ADMIN'
  end

  def super?
    super_admin == true
  end
end
```

Comment: Please paste your routes file and AdminUser model.

Comment: I have this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is `admin.password` returning the actual password? Or the encrypted version?

Also, since you are logging in as an admin user, `current_user` is actually `current_admin_user`. Devise will create the function based on your Devise mapping, it is not always `current_user`.

This is also true for namespaces, for ex

```
namespace :api do
  devise_for :users
end
```

Will cause the helper method to be `current_api_user`.

Comment: admin.password is returning an actual password. When I have checked current_user, it has been returning the AdminUser, but I think I should change it to check current_admin_user that you speak of.

I should note current_user populates fine outside of the test.

Comment: current_admin_user is also nil for me :(